# How to update a column dynamically with the current value of another column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm looking to write an update statement something like below:

```
update table set
comments = NVL (null, acknowledgement_status),
acknowledgement_status = 'Acknowledge',
alert_updated_time = sysdate,
acknowledged_by = 'Allen'
where alert_id = 8;
```

Actually, the values need to be updated from a JSP page. If a user fails to give a comment, then the corresponding `acknowledgement_status` that the user gives should be updated as `comments`. But from the above query, the previous `acknowledgement_status` is being set as `comments`. How to go about this?

Consider the table content as below:

```
    Alert_ID   Acknowledgement_status   Comments   Alert_updated_time   Acknowledged_by
    --------   ----------------------   --------   ------------------   ---------------
8               OPEN                    None                              AUTO
```

Now above is the table content. The JSP has comments field a text box and `acknowledgement_status` as drop down. When the user changes the `Acknowlegement_status` with comments as blank, I want the acknowledgement status to be updated as comment. i.e:

```
update table set
comments = NVL (textbox.value, acknowledgement_status),
acknowledgement_status = dropdown.value,
alert_updated_time = sysdate,
acknowledged_by = sessionid.value;
where alert_id = 8;
```

when `textbox.value = null, dropdown.value = 'Acknowledge', sessionid.value = 'Allen'` the table gets updated as below:

```
  Alert_ID   Acknowledgement_status   Comments   Alert_updated_time   Acknowledged_by
  --------   ----------------------   --------   ------------------   ---------------
    8            Acknowledge            OPEN          sysdate                 Allen
```

but what I want is:

```
  Alert_ID   Acknowledgement_status    Comments       Alert_updated_time   Acknowledged_by
  --------   ----------------------    --------       ------------------   ---------------
    8            Acknowledge           Acknowledge           sysdate                 Allen
```

I can rather write,

```
update table set
comments = NVL (textbox.value, dropdown.value),
acknowledgement_status = dropdown.value,
alert_updated_time = sysdate,
acknowledged_by = sessionid.value;
where alert_id = 8;
```

But again, I have plans to `decode` based on `dropdown.value` and I thought it would be easier if it was possible to update with the current value.

Help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you mean by previous `acknowledgement_status`?

Comment: What is the value that user gives? is it the `'Acknowledge'`?

Comment: @Polppan: by previous acknowledgement_status what I mean is, the value that was already present before this update statement.

Comment: @zephyrus You mean the value which is already exists in table?

Comment: What if you do `comments = COALESCE('comment_provided_by_user', 'Acknowledge'),`

Comment: @zephyrus Have you tried the case approach which I have posted as answer?

Comment: @zephyrus Perhaps you need to provide your java code as well.

Comment: @Polppan: yeah I did. Did not work. And yes I could work around the JAVA code validating with a few `if` conditions. But again, I would like to learn if this possible from oracle end. Like, `:new.acknowledgement_status` as used in Triggers but in a single update statement.

Comment: @ypercube: Did not work.

Comment: How doesn't this work? It's the same as your last code: *"I can rather write, ..."*

Comment: @zephyrus When you mention previous `acknowledgement_status` does it mean the value which exists in table before the update? E.g. `OPEN` value in `Comments` columnm, does this value already exists in your table?

Comment: @Polppan: Yes. Already exists.

Comment: @ypercube: Well, it did set the comments field to 'Acknowledge' when the user provided coments is `NULL`. But not the current `acknowledgement_status` which is what I needed.

Comment: @zephyrus if that is the case `nvl`, `case when null` statements will not work because it checks for value exists in your table and in this case it is not null, it will not update `Comments` column. Hence you are always getting the previous value even after the update.

Comment: I meant `comments = COALECSE(textbox.value, dropdown.value),` (I had made that comment before you updated the question), which is essentially the same as your code. `NVL()` and `COALESCE()` are similar functions.

Comment: @Polppan: Yeah. Guess I have to make the validations on server side only.

Comment: @ypercube: Probably that is what I might end up with. Thanks all for the time and advice.

Comment: @zephyrus See comments in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, if you want to pass the values only once:

```
UPDATE tableX t
SET 
  (comments, acknowledgement_status, alert_updated_time, acknowledged_by)
=
  ( SELECT 
      COALESCE(com, ack_st), ack_st, sd, ack_by
    FROM
    ( SELECT 
        textbox.value    AS com,
        dropdown.value   AS ack_st,
        sysdate          AS sd,
        sessionid.value  AS ack_by
      FROM dual
    ) d
  )              
WHERE t.alert_id = 8 ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93239/4)**

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Worked beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 update table set comments  =   
 case when (comments  is null) then acknowledgement_status else  comments   end,
 acknowledgement_status = 'Acknowledge',
 alert_updated_time = sysdate,
 acknowledged_by = 'Allen'
 where alert_id = 8;
```

Trigger approach

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON table     FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

begin

    if (:new.comments is null) then

    :new.comments := :new.acknowledgement_status;

    end if;

END;
/
```

Comment: worked same as `comments = NVL (textbox.value, acknowledgement_status)`

Comment: @zephyrus As you have mentioned that column Comments is not null, then  `nvl`, `case when null` statements will not work because it checks for value exists in your table and in this case it is not null, it will not update `Comments` column. Hence you are always getting the previous value even after the update. Best bet in this case would be to use a `update trigger` on your table.

Comment: Writing trigger for this is like making two updates which I am tracking in another table with a trigger already. So this would make two entries into the table. Or again I have to modify my old trigger to include this as well. Anyway, I shall try this.

Comment: @zephyrus I have edited my answer, try with your existing trigger if you wouldn't like to create a new trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set
comments = decode(comment, null, 'Acknowledge', comment),
acknowledgement_status = 'Acknowledge',
alert_updated_time = sysdate,
acknowledged_by = 'Allen'
where alert_id = 8;
```

This will update the `comment` field to `Acknowledge` if the value is `null`. Not sure about that "prevoius" thing you mentioned. If you need something else, then you should update your question with a clearer description.

Since you want to updated according to other states as well, you can stack the `decode` because it essentially acts like an `if...then..else`

Comment: worked same as `update table set
comments = NVL (textbox.value, acknowledgement_status),
acknowledgement_status = dropdown.value,
alert_updated_time = sysdate,
acknowledged_by = sessionid.value;
where alert_id = 8;`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET comments = COALESCE(comment, acknowledgement_status),
    acknowledgement_status = 'Acknowledge',
    alert_updated_time = SYSDATE,
    acknowledged_by = 'Allen'
WHERE alert_id = 8;
```

Comment: worked same as `comments = NVL (textbox.value, acknowledgement_status)`